# Chevron in MathJax

Tags: support, mathjax

How do I write a chevron/circum (^) in MathJax? A backslash doesn't work as an escape character.

(Specific context: using *x*^*y* to mean XOR as in $x\oplus y$. It's not my choice of notation so don't tell me that I can just use a different symbol.)

Comment: Basically all possibles ways (with LaTeX, not with MathJax) are in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77647.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is $x\hat{}y$ acceptable? Gotten with `$x\hat{}y$`. In-line I have used 
`$x$^$y$` which produces $x$^$y$. To get that effect in a displayed formula, an obvious work around is to wrap it in a text box
$$
\text{$x$^$y$}
$$
produced with the snippet `$$\text{$x$^$y$}$$`.

Comment: I'm sure TeXperts know of better ways, but tweaks like that were common in the plainTeX-era.

Answer (score 4):

I'd imagine $\land$ would be the right symbol here as an operator, so `\land` (logical and) or `\wedge` will produce $\land$ (and $\wedge$).

But it might not be the same as $x$^$y$ if you write $x\land y$. It's up to you to decide if you like it or not. In either case, be sure to clarify the notation, which normally means "and" rather than "xor".

You can try $x^\land y$ as well.

Comment: I can see a typeset version of the symbol (but not its source) and it's definitely a superscript rather than an infix.

Comment: @Adam: How about the edit?

Comment: Ah, using a superscript *and* \land hadn't occurred to me. Good idea.

Comment: The spacing above bothers me, as the caret is being parsed as a superscript on $x$.  Perhaps $x\mathbin{{}^\land} y$ would work?  This is typeset as `$x\mathbin{{}^\land} y$`.  I also think that `\land` should probably be replaced by `\wedge` (they are synonymous and are typeset identically, but `\wedge` feels more general).

Comment: @Xander: Yes, I was also bothered by this. I'd think you suggest the right approach here. Or with a lack of spacing, $x{{}^\wedge\!}y$.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you use MathJax in a post, use this command:

`\newcommand{\^}{\text{^}}`

If you apply it by itself, it will just make a tiny blank space: $\newcommand{\^}{\text{^}}$.

Thenceforth, every time you use `\^`, you will get a chevron: $x\^y$.